# Are mods have been assigned a specific job in moderating the site?

Tags: discussion

I am member of sec.se for about 8-9 months and since we have 3 mods [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder) , [Rory Alosp](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/485/rory-alsop) and [AviD](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/33/avid) . But what I observed generally is that schroeder is highly active on main site, Rory Alosp is usually active on [DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) and meta while AviD only seen on meta.

So my main question is:-  Is there any specific job is assigned to each mod or they moderate the site in the way they want?

PS All above observations are strictly personal (maybe I would be wrong) and One thing I wanted to make clear is that my intent is not to disrespect any mod because this question is *just* for information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daya - we all have the same role. And that covers the entire site. Most of what a mod does should be invisible to the wider community - we clean up when posts are flagged, we reign in people whose behaviour isn't pleasant, and we crack down on breaches of the rules.

I am present in a lot of chat rooms, but that doesn't necessarily mean I am active in the DMZ. I respond to pings for a mod there, and try to keep an eye on it, as do the other mods. And we all respond to flags, which is the main route by which mods become aware of issues that need action.

We ourselves have a tally of moderator actions and activity, and of course SE employees can monitor all our activities.

So don't worry that your observations are misleading.

Answer (score 6):

There are no specific assignments or roles. Each one volunteers their time as they see the need.

[And we actually have 4 mods](https://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) :)

Answer (score 5):

Super secret greatly disrespected stealth mod #4 here :)

There are no specific jobs. We're in vastly different timezones, and our activity varies a lot. When we added Schroeder as the most recent mod, our newest friend handles more flags than anybody, so I come here to something quiet and became a much less visible mod. I tent to check in daily, however, and when Schroeder was on vacation there was a lot more visibility from me.

All of handle all of it, just some of us get to certain areas faster or more frequently than others.